# Finding palindromics sequences of length 18 in FASTA file?

Tags: python, substring

I want to design guide RNAs to find palindromic sequences in a FASTA file. I want to write a python script that finds all the palindromic sequences of length 18 throughout my sequence. I have a logic in mind but I don't know how to put  it in Python words. My logic is:

```
1)If i is [ATCG] and i+17 is [TAGC] then check: 
2)if i+1 is [ATCG] and i+16 is [TAGC] then check: 
3)if i+2 is [ATCG] and i+15 is [TAGC] then check"
.
.
.

10)if i+9 is [ATCG] and i+10 is [TAGC] and all the above are true,
```

then recognize the sequence of i to i+17 as a palindromic. But I need to make sure that for an A for i it considers only T for i+17.
Any idea how I write this logic in python?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to match A+T and G+C. We can use a dictionary for that. Then we just check if opposite sides are pairs.

```
pairs = {"A":"T", "T":"A", "G":"C", "C":"G"}
for i in range(len(sequence) - 18 + 1):
    pal = True
    for j in range(9):
        if pairs[ sequence[i+j] ] != sequence[i+17-j]:
            pal = False
            break
    if pal:
        print(sequence[i : i+18])
```

For any n-length palindrome (including odd n):

```
pairs = {"A":"T", "T":"A", "G":"C", "C":"G"}
n=18
for i in range(len(sequence) - n + 1):
    pal = True
    for j in range(n//2):
        if pairs[ sequence[i+j] ] != sequence[i-j+n-1]:
            pal = False
            break
    if pal:
        print(sequence[i : i+n])
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. Do you know how I can choose among these palindromes the ones that are followed by "[ATCG]CC" or "[ATCG]GG in the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Looping individually through strings takes too much time. String handling is way more efficient in Python.

```
#create random test sequence
import random
random.seed(1234)
seq = "".join(random.choices(["A", "T", "C", "G"], k=99))
n = 4 #not exactly 18 but good enough as a test case
print(seq)
>>>GTAGGCCAGAAGTCCAAAATGACTCACTCCTTAGTCACAATTACACAGGGATATGAAGAGATTTGTGTGGTGGTAATACGTGCCTCGAGTAGCGTATAT

#dictionary because translation
bp = {"A":"T", "T":"A", "G":"C", "C":"G"}

#checks if first half translates into reversed second half
#returns False if not, e.g., if the length ls of s is not an even number
def palin(s):
    ls = len(s)
    if ls%2:
        return False        
    return s[:ls//2]=="".join([bp[i] for i in s[ls:ls//2-1:-1]])

#now to the actual test, checking all substrings of length n in our test sequence seq
#returns tuples of the index within seq and the found substring 
res = [(i, seq[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(seq)-n+1) if palin(seq[i:i+n])]
print(res)
>>>[(3, 'GGCC'), (38, 'AATT'), (50, 'ATAT'), (77, 'ACGT'), (84, 'TCGA'), (94, 'TATA'), (95, 'ATAT')]
```